# A new type of drugs or a new type of drug

Tags: countable-nouns, partitives

In the grammar textbook I've been reading, there is a class of partitive constructions called 'Partition in respect of quality' with an example as below:

> a new *kind* of *computer* → new *kinds* of *computers*

[image: Examples from the book]
Why is it that the plural construction require both nouns to be in their plural forms while the singular one doesn't ? I find this intriguing because usually the count noun after *of* is in its plural form regardless of the partitive noun as in:

> a kilo of apples

Interestingly enough, class seems to be a 'quality' partitive noun as well yet somehow *a class of drug* feels less appropriate than *a class of drugs*. I wondered if the former construction is actually acceptable and I'm just assuming things.

Edit: After looking up Webster's Dictionary of English Usage on page 576 ([Webster's dictionary](https://list-english.ru/img/newpdf/dictpdf/6.pdf)), it appears that there hasn't been a consensus regarding the structure of these constructions.
[image: Webster's dictionary]
Please share your thoughts about this and if possible, about other similar but less common nouns in the screenshot below. (I took it from this website: [Similar nouns](https://www.eltconcourse.com/training/inservice/lexicogrammar/classifiers_partitives.html))
[image: ExamplesNo2]

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard anyone say "a kilos of apples"; always "a kilo of apples".

Comment: Oops, my bad. I've edited it. Still, from my observation, it appears that the plurality of both nouns will be in concord if the latter noun is countable. Do other words like 'breed', 'class' or 'variety' behave the same way ?

Comment: I would say "a breed of dog" is the only way I'd expect to hear that particular phrase--never "a breed of dogs"--but with less familiar animals you might hear it either way--"a breed of horse" or "a breed of horses".

Comment: Well, I think I would go with the usual observed style since it feels more natural that way. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Hearth, it may be different where you live, but around here it would always be "a breed of horse" and only plural with collective nouns: "a string of horses".

Comment: You would say "a new type of drug" or "a new class of drugs" because a type is singular and a class is plural.

Comment: Please, please, please give the title of the grammar book you are studying from. And if it's possible, can you also add a link to the source (IN the question though!)

Comment: It's 'A comprehensive grammar of the English language' by Randolph Quirk. An online pdf version is unavailable so I'll try to upload a screenshot instead

Answer (score 6):

In the expression "*a new kind of drug*", 'kind' is singular, presumably because you are referring to just one new kind, or type. There may be many drugs within this kind, but the group term is singular. 'Drug' is singular because it is being used as a *generic noun* - it isn't countable. In much the same way, instead of saying "types of drug", you could create a compound noun and say "*drug types*".

So, in your question, you could have said:

> a class of partitive **construction**.

Comment: Oh, that sounds sensible. But one thing that keeps bugging me is that whenever I use the online grammar checking program and type either 'a type of computers' or 'types of computer', it will immediately try to correct me. Also the textbook gives no rules or comments about this, which leaves me stumped.

Comment: @BrackBruno well, the first one of those is definitely wrong, as per my answer. The second one seems fine but perhaps you are using it with an article? Or other context that would make plural 'types' incorrect?

Comment: I tried 'New types of computer have been invented.' and the website (quillbot.com) suggested changing to 'computers'.

Comment: Grammar-checking programs aren't perfect, unfortunately.  They might be good for proof-reading your work for accidental errors, but they tend to be less useful for learning from.

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks strange to me.  The first half ("*a new kind of computer*") looks fine, but the usual plural would be "**new kinds of computer**" - we're talking of more than one *new kind* but the qualifier ("*of computer*") shouldn't be changed.

You wouldn't normally¹ hear a plural in the qualifier, whatever the count of the noun itself.

And yes, words such as "example", "instance" and "variety" share the same construction.

---

¹ In Britain, at least - I'm no authority on foreign dialects of English.

Comment: I'm learning E as a second language and currently using CGEL by Randolph Quirk and so the aforementioned examples are taken directly from the book. That said, the book doesn't really explain the examples so I'm quite befuddled. Especially so when I look up similar nouns denoting 'quality partition' like breed, species, class or variety and they don't appear to obey such constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue has to do with countable and uncountable nouns. "Computer" is a countable noun: you cannot use the singular to refer to a class, group, collection, etc, of computers, so "a kind of computer" is fine, but "kinds of computers" needs "computers" to be pluralized.

Compare with "a new kind of computer technology" and "new kinds of computer technology", where "[technology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/technology)" is being used in its [*uncountable*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#uncountable) sense of a collection of techniques.